# Jest Typescript: mock doesn't return expected shape

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a TypeScript file that I'm trying to mock with Jest.  Here is the file:

```
export class Logger {
  log(message) => {console.log(message); }
}
```

The class I am unit testing has `Logger` as a dependency so I'm trying to create a mock that will be reusable in other tests.  Here is my attempt at a mock:

```
export const MockLogger = jest.fn<Logger, any>(() => {
  const mockedObject = {
    log: jest.fn()
  };

  return mockedObject;
});
```

In my test file I import the constant and try to use it.

```
import {MyService} from './my-service';
import {MockLogger} from './mock-logger';

describe('...', () => {
  let service: MyService; // depends on Logger
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    service = new MyService(MockLogger());
  });
});
```

But `MockLogger()` logs as `undefined`.  I've also tried injecting `new MockLogger()` and that appears to be a `mockConstructor {}`.  Don't know what that is; either way, neither has the `.log()` function that `MyService` wants to call.

Using `jest@^24.9` and `typescript@^3.6`

#### Additional Info

It must have to do with the timing of execution. If i place the same exact mock at the beginning of the test itself, it works.

#### Think I got it

The `jest.resetAllMocks()` in my before each clears out the mock before it has a chance to be used.

Comment: I had to handle a similar usecase.  I ended up extracting an interface from `Logger`, refactored all code to depend on the interface instead of the concrete class, added a `MockLogger` class that implements that interface but did nothing, and then just used `jest.mock('mocked module')` to decorate `MockLogger` with jest's things.